# How do you use encrypted passwords in a Symfony configuration file?

Tags: encryption, configuration, passwords, symfony

I am working on Symfony 3 a project that will ultimately run on a web server that is managed by someone else.

I would like to encrypt all of the passwords in the various Symfony configuration files.

Is there a supported way to do this?

Comment: Could you tell what types of password do you need to store in configuration? What are they used for? In fact, you shouldn't put any passwords in config files. It's one of biggest wrong practices, but if you really need it, I will help you.

Comment: What does "managed by someone else" mean exactly? And what's the reasoning for storing encrypted passwords in config files?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @michail_w, This is a Symfony application. So, database passwords (two different ones), a master password for authenticating users on via a remote system (don't ask; it's legacy), SMPT servers, etc.

Comment: @AlvinBunk, It means the server belongs to my customer's customer and that I have very little control over how it will be managed and who will have access to the files on it.

Comment: @zaph, This is not a user authentication database. These are configuration files and I would like to make it at least a little bit more difficult to obtain any passwords (see my previous comment in response to @michail_w).

Comment: May I ask some more questions? What are you trying to protect in your Symfony application? In other words, why do users need passwords? Can you use authentication against another LDAP or Active Directory server instead?

Comment: Interesting that this is a top result in google for encrypting passwords in Symfony configuration files. None of the responses above seem to understand the concern. The problem is that storing passwords in plain text in a common config file is a horrible security practice. It's not an uncommon feature to be able to encrypt certain strings in a file so that the value can only be decrypted by the process running it (such as a connection string type password in a web.config file). Unfortunately I can find no such feature or examples of someone implementing this.

Comment: @ Alvin Bunk, It has nothing to do with users. Please see @ChadSikorra's comment. He puts it very well.

Comment: It's possible to encrypt the password of the database in parameters.yml?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. This may not be as big an issue in Symfony 4 since ENV variables are now the recommended way to supply some of this stuff to the Symfony app.